# Null data returned from JSON

Tags: android, json, fragment

I have already done this task for another project and it gave JSON values but for this code when I use the `extends Fragment`, it show null value. 
Following is the `Fragment` extended class code:

**Note:** I'm using same `ServiceHandler` class as previous project

```
public class NewsActivity extends Fragment {

private NewsActivity activity;

//  url to get JSON
private static String url = "http://vikashparajuli.orgfree.com/zz/get_all_products.php";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container, false);
    activity = this;

    //TODO: if Internet is connected
    if(AutoLifeUtils.isConnectedToInternet(getActivity())){
        new Get_postlist().execute();       
    }else{

    }
    return rootView;
}

public  class Get_postlist extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
          }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to API url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

        }

}

}
```

Here is `ServiceHandler` class

```
public class ServiceHandler {

static String response = null;
public final static int GET = 1;
public final static int POST = 2;

/**
 * Making service call
 * @url - url to make request
 * @method - http request method
 * */

public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method){

    return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);

}

 /**
 * Making service call
 * @url - url to make request
 * @method - http request method
 * @params - http request params
 * */

private String makeServiceCall(String url, int method, List<NameValuePair> params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
        // http client
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

        // Checking http request method type
        if (method == POST) {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            // adding post params
            if (params != null) {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));  // UrlEncodedFormEntity() is useful to send HTTP POST request
            }

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        } else if (method == GET) {
            // appending params to url
            if (params != null) {
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
            }
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        }
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);


    }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(ClientProtocolException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException exc){
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

Comment: extent FragmentActivity

Comment: i can not extend FragmentActivity because it gives error for another class. Is there any way for Fragment

Comment: i have edit the question in which i have add **ServiceHandler** class

Comment: your sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET) call is returning null at the end of the method.

Comment: Please return "response" object at the end of your method instead of null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the makeServiceCall you have **return null;**

change it to **return response;** as shown below.

```
private String makeServiceCall(String url, int method, List<NameValuePair> params) {

     ....
    //return null;
      return response; //this should fix your problem. 
}
```